# PHP concatenating multiple variables

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

I'm very new to PHP.  I'm trying to insert some values into a database so I'm using PHP and MySQL but I'm struggling to concatenate the following string.  I keep getting the error "unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING" for the following line no matter where I place the "."-

```
$query "INSERT INTO users(user_name, email_address, password)
          VALUES ('".$user_name."','".$email_address."','".$password."')";
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Avoid concatenation completely and use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead. The way you're building the query makes you open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work). Prepared statements are not only safe, but will also properly quote all your parameters.

Comment: There was an `=` sign missing between the variable `$query` and the string literal following - that might be where the problem was, if indeed, you were actually missing the `=` sign in your own code as well

Comment: @MikeDinescu Apologies I amended the post before you posted your comment - I wasn't sure if you unintentionally added the `=` or not. Should I undo my edit?

Comment: @TheCodesee - no it's fine, I've updated my comment as well. Most likely that's where the error was coming from, now that I think about it

Comment: @TheCodesee IMO you did well. One shouldn't fix the typos in code, especially when it's the cause of the problem

Comment: @Cid -- agreed; after I typed my comment I was considering actually going back myself to revert my edit since that's actually most likely where the problem was

Comment: For what it's worth, the question linked in the closed vote may actually not help Steph that much since the problem (and solutions discussed on that question) are about alternating quotation marks. In this case however, the problem is most likely the missing `=` sign between the variable and the string literal following after.